# How to add Panel on mouse location?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to add a Panel (which is on other panel) on mouse position. When I add now, panel's location is next to previous panel.

```
  jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
  newPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
  jPanel1.add(newPanel);

  newPanel.setLocation(300,300);
  jPanel1.revalidate();
  jPanel1.repaint();


  Point point = newPanel.getLocation();
  int x = point.x;
  int y = point.y;
  newPanel.setLocation(x+5,y+5);
```

Comment: `setLocation(...)` does not work for most layout managers. What effect overall are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And if you're trying to move a rectangle, then there are much easier ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I`d like to change position of added panel to mouse clicked position. I know how to get Mouse position but I dont know how to change added panel position.

Comment: But again, what are you doing with the moving JPanel? Are you using it to draw a red square, or does it serve another purpose? This is important as it would change the entire approach to a solution.

Comment: I am using it to draw square.

Comment: Shall I use setBound ()?

Comment: No -- if all you're doing is drawing a square, if you're not using it in a "component" way, then do just that -- draw a square within paintComponent.

Comment: Yes but need to have object of painted object.

Comment: I am trying to draw graph with vertex and edges

Comment: Ah, you should have said this from the get-go. Again I would urge you not to create a JPanel as this is much too heavy-weight for what you're trying to achieve. Instead a Model-View is what you need.

Comment: You really should include all pertinent information in your question from the start, to avoid having us spin our wheels.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll remember :)

Comment: `I am using it to draw square.` - then you should be doing custom painting on the panel. Keep an ArrayList of all the squares you want to draw then in the paint component method you iterate through the ArrayList and paing all the objects. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to place a Swing component in a random position, then you will need a layout manager that would allow this, and FlowLayout, along with most standard managers, won't. The most common one to use is the simplest -- a null layout, e.g., `someJPanel.setLayout(null);` -- that is complete absence of a layout manager, but this comes with its own host of troubles, and so I try to avoid use of these as much as possible.

If your goal however is to move a red square, then best to keep things as simple as possible, and instead of creating and moving a JPanel, create and move something much lighter in weight, a Rectangle.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MovingRect extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final int RECT_W = 300;
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, RECT_W, RECT_W);

    public MovingRect() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));

        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(rect);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point p0;
        private Point pRect;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }

            if (rect.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                p0 = e.getPoint();
                pRect = rect.getLocation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 != null) {
                drag(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (p0 != null) {
                drag(e);
                p0 = null;
            }
        }

        private void drag(MouseEvent e) {
            // use simple geometry to move the rectangle
            Point p1 = e.getPoint();
            int x = p1.x - p0.x + pRect.x;
            int y = p1.y - p0.y + pRect.y;
            rect = new Rectangle(x, y, RECT_W, RECT_W);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MovingRect mainPanel = new MovingRect();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moving Rectangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Code explanation

The rectangle to draw, initially placed at 0, 0:

```
private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, RECT_W, RECT_W);
```

In the constructor, set the drawing JPanel's preferred size, and create our mouse listener (actually a MouseAdapter) that will move the rectangle, and add the MouseAdapter as a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to our drawing (main) JPanel:

```
public MovingRect() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));

    MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
    addMouseListener(myMouse);
    addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
}
```

Draw the rectangle within this JPanel's paintComponent method after doing clean-up painting by calling the super's method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
    ((Graphics2D) g).fill(rect);
}
```

The mouse adapater that does the moving. It uses simple geometry of vector addition to calculate where to move

```
private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    private Point p0;
    private Point pRect;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            // if not button 1, then get out of here
            return;
        }

        if (rect.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            // get the first point of the mouse press and the rectangle's first position
            p0 = e.getPoint();
            pRect = rect.getLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (p0 != null) {
            drag(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (p0 != null) {
            drag(e);
            p0 = null; // set the first pressed point to null -- stop the listener
        }
    }

    private void drag(MouseEvent e) {
        // use simple geometry to move the rectangle
        Point p1 = e.getPoint();
        int x = p1.x - p0.x + pRect.x;
        int y = p1.y - p0.y + pRect.y;

        // create a new Rectangle with the position calculated above
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, RECT_W, RECT_W);

        // ask Java to repaint the main JPanel
        repaint();
    }

}
```